# How to store multiple form $_POST in session

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I try to store in $_SESSION each $_POST send from input,
So i have search bar, somebody can send query multiple times and ultimately gets the result from all query from search.
My problem is, that $_SESSION store each time only last form action. In the meantime, I check if his query is in the database and display the data from the database, if it exists

```
function search()
{
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['fraza'])) {
        $_SESSION['fraza'] = array();
    }

    global $wpdb, $user_ID;
    $query_form_value;
    $data = array();
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'pozycje';
    $domain = get_site_url();

    if (isset($_POST['wyszukaj']) && !empty($_POST['wyszukiwarka'])) {
        $search_array = array();
        $array_exists = array();
        $sql = ('SELECT * FROM wp_pozycje ');

        $fraza = $_POST['wyszukiwarka'];
        //array_push( $search_array, $fraza);

        array_push($_SESSION['fraza'], $fraza);

        $exists_results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

        print_r($_SESSION['fraza']);
        echo '</br>';

        foreach ($exists_results as $exists) {
            $array_exists[] = $exists->numer;
        }

        $results_array = array_intersect($search_array, $array_exists);
        echo 'tablica z bazy</br>';
        print_r($array_exists);

        echo 'tablica z porownania</br>';
        print_r($results_array);

    }
}

search();
```

Answer (score 3):

You are resetting the array everytime with this code:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['fraza'])){
    $_SESSION['fraza']= array();
}
```

I guess you are trying to check if this index `fraza` exists or not. If not exists, then create. In this case use `! isset` instead

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['fraza'])){
    $_SESSION['fraza']= array();
}
```

Comment: I second that, you are resetting this value on each request.

Comment: This is why the “simple” `$foo[]=` syntax is so much preferable over `array_push`, IMHO. You can do `$_SESSION['fraza'][] = $fraza;` without having to check if `$_SESSION['fraza']` actually exists beforehand, PHP will create the proper array at this point, and not complain. The same thing done via array_push, gets you a _“Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given”_

Comment: No problem @ncti .. if it works for you please mark the answer as accepted to help others with the same issue.